# database performance and json

Tags: sql-server, database, database-normalization

I am new to database performance issues and have a question about best practices. I have a database table that has over 10,000 pairs of cities and states such as

- Dallas, Texas
- Houston, Texas
- Miami, Florida

Someone told me that the best practice would be to have cities and states in different tables and reference them with a composite index.

I forgot to mention that these locations are used with a `Json` textbox with auto-completion. Does this change things or should I still have separate tables?

If i should leave them on same table, would it be best to index both fields or just one?

The way the textbox are used is similar to google searches were you type in a question and you get suggestions right below that. If a user's types in "Hou" then Houston, Texas would start to appear below textbox. The textbox is only used for searches never any inserts or updates.

```
    var zipps = db.zipss.Where(s => s.city.Contains(id) && s.state.Contains(tid)).Take(5).Select(b => b.city + "," + b.stateabbr).ToList().Distinct();
                return Json(zipps, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search your data by text fields and not by `id`, then you need to create your indexes on these text fields.

How does search work on your data? You type the name of the city and get group of cities with it' states?
Then you need one index on the names of the cities.

If we are talking only about this query `s => s.city.Contains(id) && s.state.Contains(tid)`, then composite index on these two rows will help you find data much faster.